# Persist association symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, associations, persistence

I started using Doctrine2 and associations but I don't understand all aspects.

I've 2 php class :

```
class User extends BaseUser
{     
    protected $id;

    protected $team;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer $id
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function getTeam() {
    return $this->team;
}

public function setTeam($team) {
    $this->team = $team;
}


}
```

and

```
/**
 * Team
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="basket__team")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Tperroin\BasketBundle\Entity\TeamRepository")
 */
class Team
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="categorie", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $categorie;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="basket__team_user_coach")
 */
private $coachs;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="basket__team_user_player")
 */
private $players;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="level", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $level;
```

My problem is that when a user create a new profile the association is not created.

So I've this function in my User class with a PostPersist:

```
public function addTeam(LifecycleEventArgs $args) { 

    $entity = $args->getEntity(); 
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();

    $player = $this->getTeam();

    $player->setPlayers(array($entity));

    $em->persist($player);
    $em->flush();
}
```

It works but just for one user, my function generate a delete query before the insert one.

is there a solution for this kind of problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your ORM annotation : both `$coach` and `$players` have a targetEntity of User and the same inveredBy attribute. `inversedBy` should be the attribute of User class that is the other side of the many to many association, for exemple repectively `$coachedTeams` and `$playInTeams`.

Your addTeam code remove previous associations because you call `$player->setPlayers(array($entity))`: it replace the old collection of associations by the new one. You should call $player->addPlayer($entity) instead, to add a new object to the existing collection.

If you generated your entities with `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities`, you should not have method `setPlayers()` but `addPlayer()` and `removePlayer()`.

Please also note that association with Doctrine are stored as `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection` and not plain array.

Comment: Rookie mistake sorry... the addPlayer function works great of course ! I've modified my annotation and I use the Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection. Thank you for all